# Detecting a trend in 4 samples

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have 4 levels for a single factor, which is called "Compliance".

Compliance has an ordinal scale (0, 1, 2, 3) and it is computed as the number of rules a team complies with.

My hypothesis is the following: "the more you comply, the more effective you are". Effectiveness is a real positive number.

I have 4 independent samples, one for each compliance.

My questions are:
1) Can I apply Jonckheere-Terpstra?

2) If I apply J-T and it succeeds, I can only conclude the existence of a weak monotony. I would like to check whether there are significant differences among pairs. In particular, I would like to check the following: C=0 vs C=1, C=1 vs C=2 and C=2 vs C=3. What test should I run? Should I apply any correction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I checked the literature and the answer seems to be yes, I can apply that test.
2) Again, yes, independent t-tests are appropriate and no correction (e.g. Bonferroni) is needed.